# Surfaces whose geodesics are algebraic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry

What, if anything, can be said about a surface whose geodesics are all algebraic? One example is of course the sphere.

Comment: ...and the plane.

Comment: If the surface is compact, then all geodesics have to be closed. There is a very nice book by Besse on manifolds whose geodesics are all closed, but I do not recall if he considers those which are also algebraic.

Comment: If you allow a Lorentz metric on the ambient space, the hyperboloid model of the hyperbolic plane.

Comment: Mariano, there are few of them in dimension 2. Basically it is the problem of algberaic integrability of the geodesic flow on a surface. You need one extra integral (besides the square of the length). Ellipsoid (done by Jacobi in elliptical coordinates) and surfaces of revolution (Clairaut's  relation) are the most prominent genus 0 examples.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the simplest example of a non-algebraic geodesic?  

Comment: I have an even more basic question: what does it mean for a geodesic to be algebraic?  Is the condition satisfied by an irrational winding on a flat torus?

Comment: Pete, on a torus of revolution in $R^3$ there is a mixture of positive and negative Gauss curvature. So, fixing a point on the outer rim, by symmetry arguments one can describe three types of geodesics. If the angle with the outer "equator" is small, repetitive but not winding. If the angle is large enough, nearly orthogonal to the equator, repetive and winding. At a certain critical angle in the middle, the geodesic approaches the inner "equator" but never reaches it. This last type is not algebraic, whatever can happen with the others.

Comment: @Scott: I think the OP means that the geodesic should be (contained in) a subvariety.

Comment: See Sinclair and Tanaka "A Bound on the Number of Endpoints of the Cut Locus" page 2 out of 19 in this pdf:

www.lms.ac.uk/jcm/9/lms2005-018/sub/lms2005-018.pdf 

Evidently the first characterization was Gilbert A. Bliss (1902) "The geodesic lines on the anchor ring" Ann. of Math. (2) 4 (1902) 1-21.

Glad I got this one right, I worked it out by continuity arguments.

Comment: I've just found this paper by Kozlov that considers the existence of algebraic geodesics on algebraic surfaces. It's a related problem but not really what I asked: 
V. V. Kozlov, "Topology of real algebraic curves and the integrability of geodesic flows on algebraic surfaces."
Funct. Anal. Appl. 42 (2008), no. 2, 98--102. MR2438015 (2009d:37101)
http://www.springerlink.com/content/72W1645U0P822LT9 


Answer (score 1):

A class of examples is provided by projective spaces, in which case [prime closed geodesics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_geodesic) are great circles on spheres.

See Klingenberg's [*Lectures on Closed Geodesics*](http://books.google.com/books?id=HkmhUkJj3pUC), p. 178, Theorem 5.2.1. The relevant page is not available on Google, but is accessible on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540083936).